# valence desire 2 learn profile image upload error 404

Tags: image, upload, profile, desire2learn, valence

I'm trying to upload an image profile using the api but I'm getting a Unknown: NOT_FOUND 404 error. the call I am using is POST /d2l/api/lp/1.3/profile/(profileId)/image, I am passing the content type, length and filename (profileImage). I'm passing the image as a dataStream. I've reduced the size of the image as well. Any ideas?

```
                public static void UploadFilesToRemoteUrl(string file, string logpath, NameValueCollection nvc, ID2LUserContext userContext, string accion)
    {
        var uri = userContext.CreateAuthenticatedUri(accion, "POST");
        string boundary = "bde472ff1f1a46539e54e655857c27c1";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" +
        boundary;
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, compress");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = true;

        request.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Constantes.UsuarioProxy, Constantes.PasswordProxy, Constantes.DominioProxy);

        Stream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" +
        boundary + "\r\n");


        string formdataTemplate = "\r\n--" + boundary +
        "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profileImage\"; filename=\"profileImage.png\" \r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n";

        byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formdataTemplate);
        memStream.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);


        // Read image File *************************************************************
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fileStream.Close();
        //*****************************************************************************
        //*********** End Read image file *********************************************

        memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

        request.ContentLength = memStream.Length;
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        memStream.Position = 0;
        byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
        memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
        memStream.Close();
        requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
        string responseValence = reader.ReadToEnd();

    }
```

Comment: You're trying to update someone else's profile image? What are you providing for the `profileId` parameter in the route? Are you sure it's a valid `profileId` for the user? Note that the profile ID for a user is _not_ the same as the `UserID` value...

Comment: HI! Yes, the profileId is correct and diferent of userId. The profileId used is: xXPMokhy81

Comment: Can you please add the string value for 'accion' that's provoking the 404 here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems most likely that the 404 is coming either from

- The API route you're providing (and the back-end service cannot match your API route to a handler method): this could be because of an incorrect `profileId` value, or a mis-typed route, or an incorrect API version number in the route, and so forth.
- That for some reason the back-end service is accepting your profile image data but then unable to assign it to the user's profile.

Here's a capture of some request/response details of what an uploaded profile image packet looks like. When uploading a profile image to "my profile", I use an HTTP header that gets built from these values:

```
{'Content-Length': '75143', 
 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/3.3.3 Darwin/12.5.0', 
 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=bde472ff1f1a46539e54e655857c27c1', 
 'Accept': '*/*', 
 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, compress'}
```

Note that this is a multipart/form-data content body, with a boundary marker around a single body part. The body content for the request looks like this:

```
--bde472ff1f1a46539e54e655857c27c1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profileImage"; filename="profile_img-225x225.png"

[actual PNG bytes here]
--bde472ff1f1a46539e54e655857c27c1--
```

The `name` property in the Content-Disposition header must be `profileImage`, and the `filename` property should be named after the local filename you're using to provide the content (so, as far as the back-end service is concerned, it's value is not particularly relevant).

Finally, there are particular role permissions at play that permit a user to edit someone *else's* profile image, so you should ensure that your calling user context for the API call has permission to edit someone else's image.

Comment: Thanks for your response!! The permissions were not sufficient, but now the SERVER not return error 404, return a Empty Response and the image profile of user is corrupted...

Comment: The Response Status is OK > 200 . But the image profile of user is Bad. The uplodad file is profileImage.png

Comment: This leads me to believe that you're not encoding the packet properly. All the HTTP header (and part header) portions need to be UTF-8 encoded, including the boundary strings: the data in the data part needs to be raw bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. This code works correctly:

```
        public static void UploadFilesToRemoteUrl(byte[] profileImage, ID2LUserContext userContext, string accion)
    {
        //Reference:
        //action = "/d2l/api/lp/1.3/profile/" + profileIdentifier + "/image";

        //profileImage = the profileImage of user read from disk:
        /*
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(pictureLocalPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        Byte[] img = new Byte[fileStream.Length];
        fileStream.Read(img, 0, Convert.ToInt32(img.Length));
        fileStream.Close();
        */

        var uri = userContext.CreateAuthenticatedUri(accion, "POST");
        string boundary = "bde472ff1f1a46539e54e655857c27c1";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" +
        boundary;
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, compress");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = true;

        request.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Constantes.UsuarioProxy, Constantes.PasswordProxy, Constantes.DominioProxy);

        Stream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" +
        boundary + "\r\n");


        string formdataTemplate = "\r\n--" + boundary +
        "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profileImage\"; filename=\"profileImage.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg;\r\n\r\n";

        byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formdataTemplate);
        memStream.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);

        //escribo el array de byte de la imagen
        memStream.Write(profileImage, 0, profileImage.Length);

        byte[] boundaryClose = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--");
        memStream.Write(boundaryClose, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

        StreamReader readerReq = new StreamReader(memStream);
        string stringReq = readerReq.ReadToEnd();

        request.ContentLength = memStream.Length;
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        memStream.Position = 0;
        byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
        memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
        memStream.Close();
        requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
            string responseValence = reader.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();
        }
    }
```